# Check Box tally, amount checked/unchecked

Tags: javascript, html

How do you display the number of check boxes that have been checked? I need to display a sort of tally of the amount of check boxes that are checked and have it updated automatically for a given group. I don't know what to set the value of arrays to do this if I even need that. I also attempted to use the checked attribute but that's not working either.

```
var infoArray = new Array();

function userSelection(userInput) {
  var itemName = userInput.name;
  var itemName2 = userInput.value;

  switch (itemName) {
    case "sectionR":
      {
        switch (itemName2) {
          case "repair car":
            infoArray[0] = 1;
            break;

          case "wood work":
            infoArray[0] = 1;
            break;

          case "explore forest":
            infoArray[0] = 1;
            //end of case "sectionR"
        }
        //end of sub switch
      }
      break;

    case "sectionA":
      {
        switch (itemName2) {
          case "clothing design":
            infoArray[1] = 1;
            break;

          case "public singing":
            infoArray[1] = 1;
            break;

          case "decorate":
            infoArray[1] = 1;
            //end of sub switch
        }
        // end of case sectionA
      }
      //end of main switch
  }
  var userOutput = new Array();
  for (var i = 0; i < itemName.length; i++) {
    userOutput.push(itemName[i].checked);
  }

  document.getElementById("selectionTotal").innerHTML = "R SECTION" + "&nbsp" + "," + "&nbspA SECTION" + "<br>" +
    infoArray;

  //end of userSelection() 
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of putting an `onclick` listener to each checkbox, you can put a `onchange` listener on the parent element and when the event bubbles up, handle the event.

```js
function update() { 
  document.getElementById('count').innerHTML =
      document.querySelectorAll('#checkboxes input[type="checkbox"]:checked').length
}
```

```html
<div id='checkboxes' onchange='update()'>
  <input type='checkbox'>A
  <input type='checkbox'>B
  <input type='checkbox'>C
  <input type='checkbox'>D
</div>
<div id='count'></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

It would be helpful to see your HTML, but you should be able to use [`document.querySelectorAll("input:checked").length`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document/querySelectorAll) to get the length of a [NodeList](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NodeList) containing all of the checked input elements.

Here is a quick example of how it works:

```js
function checkThis() {
    var numberChecked = document.querySelectorAll('input:checked').length;
    document.getElementById('counter').innerHTML = "Number of checked boxes: " + numberChecked;
}
```

```html
<form>
    <input type="checkbox" name="checkthis" onclick="checkThis()" />
    <br />
    <input type="checkbox" name="checkthis" onclick="checkThis()" />
    <br />
    <input type="checkbox" name="checkthis" onclick="checkThis()" />
    <br />
    <input type="checkbox" name="checkthis" onclick="checkThis()" />
    <br />
    <input type="checkbox" name="checkthis" onclick="checkThis()" />
    <br />
    <input type="checkbox" name="checkthis" onclick="checkThis()" />
    <br />
    <input type="checkbox" name="checkthis" onclick="checkThis()" />
    <br />
    <p id="counter">Number of checked boxes: 0</p>
</form>
```

If you need to target specific checkboxes, you can just get more specific in your selector by adding a class or ID (`input#id:checked`).